# Swift Class Extension Only When Conforming to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to provide an extension that only adds functionality to classes conforming to a protocol? The functionality I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
protocol Identifiable {
  var id: String { get }
}

class Model {
  func report(data: String) {
    ...
  }
}

class Thing: Model, Identifiable {
  var id: String
  ...
}

class Place: Model, Identifiable {
  var id: String
  ...
}

extension (Model + Identifiable) {

  func identifiy() {
    report("\(self.id)")
  }

}

// Invalid: Model().identify()
Place().identify() // OK
Thing().identify() // OK
```

Extending the protocol itself isn't possible because the extension requires access to methods defined on `model`. Extending model fails because the `id` is only defined on the child objects. Extending `Model: Identifiable` fails because `Model` does not conform to protocol `Identifiable`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could extend `Identifiable`, you just need to specify that `Self` is a `Model`, or subclass of `Model`:

```
extension Identifiable where Self: Model {
    func identifiy() {
        report(id) 
        // `id` is already a `String` so there's 
        // no need to use String Interpolation.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the right syntax. Appreciate the response!